# Display Word Document from Resouce file to RichTextBox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have a Word document imported into the resouce file of my project.

**Is it possible to extract this document and display it in the RichTextBox control in my application?**

I was able to extract the string and image objects from the resource file of my project using the below class.

[image]

```
namespace TestProject
{
    public class Utilities
    {
        private static ResourceManager _resource = new ResourceManager("TestProject.Resource1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        public static string GetString(string name)
        {
            return (System.String)(_resource.GetString(name));
        }

        public static Image GetImage(string name)
        {
            return (System.Drawing.Image) (_resource.GetObject(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the document saved in RTF format? If so, you should just be able to assign the resource value to the RichTextBox.RTF property. If not, I seriously doubt RichTextBox can parse other forms of Word Document.

Answer (score 1):

RTF is formatted as a string and if you add it to the Files section of the resources file, it will wrap it with a property to read the string.

That is:

```
Properties.Resources.YourDocument;
```

is implemented as:

```
    internal static string YourDocument {
        get {
            return ResourceManager.GetString("YourDocument", resourceCulture);
        }
    }
```

and return rich text looking something like this:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang3081{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0
>   Calibri;}} {\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue0;} {*\generator Msftedit
>   5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\cf1\lang9\f0\fs22
>   Rich\cf0 , multiline text.\par \par Is \b\fs32 here\b0\fs22\par }

Leaving you just needing to do:

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = RichTextResource.Properties.Resources.YourDocument
```

That assumes the document is actually saved as rich text. A word doc will show up as garbage.

Finally, if your resource is stored as a byte[], you'll need to convert to a string first. I.e.

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes), assuming its UTF8 encoded.
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, will try this one.

Comment: I checked the RTF I imported into the Resource file of my project and it is in byte[] type. I'm also not using Visual Studio so I manually get the resource values using the above class.

Comment: maybe I just need to convert this byte[] into Rtf document before assigning to `richTextBox1.Rtf`. No idea though...

Comment: Yep. richTextBox1.Rtf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes), assumign its UTF8 encoded.

Comment: Hi Steven, it worked! Kindly post your comment as an answer then I will mark it to your credit. THanks

Comment: Cool. Added it to my original. Thx.